# How to get the all types of all the props of interface into one type variable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am building a web application with Typescript. In my code, I got into a situation where I need to get all the types of every prop of an object/interface into a type variable.

I have an interface with the following code:

```
interface ProductForm {
    name: string;
    id: number | string;
    categoryId: number;
    status: ProductStatus // enum
}
```

As you can see, the above interface has 4 props and they have different types.

I want to have a function as follows:

```
const updateProductFormField = (name: keyof ProductForm, value: any) => {
   // update the field
}
```

As you can see in the above code, the function first parameter, `name` must be one of the props of the `ProductForm` interface. The second argument has type, `any` which I am trying to get rid of. The value must be one of the type of types of the props of ProductForm interface.

Basically I am trying to get all types of props of ProductForm into one variable like this:

```
type FormValueTypes = ProductForm['name'] | ProductForm['id'] | ProductForm['categoryId'] | ProductForm['status'];
```

Then use that type for second argument. But I am hardcoding in the fields in the code above? When a new field is added to the interface, I will have to change that variable too. Is that a more dynamic to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```js
interface ProductForm {
    name: string;
    id: number | string;
    categoryId: number;
    status: ProductStatus // enum
}

const updateProductFormField = <T extends keyof ProductForm>(name: T, value: ProductForm[T]) => {
   // update the field
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'd get all types in values of an interface like below:

```
interface A {}

interface ProductForm {
    name: string;
    id: number | string;
    categoryId: number;
    status: ProductStatus;
}

const updateProductFormField = (name: keyof ProductForm, value: ProductForm[keyof ProductForm]) => {
   // Type of value here is string | number | ProductStatus
}
```

However this has the problem that you can do something like:

```
updateProductFormField('status', 42);
```

To avoid this you can make the function a generic:

```
const updateProductFormField = <T extends keyof ProductForm>(name: T, value: ProductForm[T]) => {
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4F8BQPSSyIoAKUA9gCYCuCYAYuVALaY7IfIhzMQBcyAM5gooAOYBudp2CUBIaswBG0ZAB8hI8VM7IEcSGKYBPAJJyuilVB2dhB6oIGopuHAnIhhyagAdKBhBkVLQMTMz0wBAANpTIALzIABTcvAIA1hDG5DDIwTR0jCwANMgAbnDR1Px5FAVhLADamdm5%20aFFzAC6AJQJAHxsOG4eXmA%20-oHtheGRMZQATAnIADwAKsgQAB6QIJSCyC05tSEzLP0pPDVrpRVVNdMNzI1rvQNsAJDDeDh%20AZCPTpzWJJADkqQgoNKAEYAAw9KR-KZ1DqzKKxBZgiFQ5BwhE4IA)